# Extruding along y-axis is not working in the expected orientation

Tags: transform-orientation, axis

I'm trying to extrude along the y-axis pressing 'e' and than 'y' but it doesn't follow the y-axis as expected (see screenshot). It should connect to a flat surface but it's kinda diagonal and I don't know why or how to fix this. Can anyone help?

Using Blender 2.8 Beta.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried hitting y twice? - Afaik there were discussions weather or not the local axis should be used by default instead of global. So maybe that's currently being tested in your build.

Comment: You are 100 % correct. Hitting y twice solved my issue. Thank you for your help - you saved me a lot of frustration.